# Arduino - millis() - value getting value of other variable

Tags: arduino

i am trying to have a function fire every x amount without blocking the main loop, i saw some example code to do this, see code below:

```
// Interval is how long we wait
// add const if this should never change
int interval=1000;
// Tracks the time since last event fired
unsigned long previousMillis=0;


void loop() { 
  // Get snapshot of time
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  Serial.print("TIMING: ");
  Serial.print(currentMillis);
  Serial.print(" - ");
  Serial.print(previousMillis);
  Serial.print(" (");
  Serial.print((unsigned long)(currentMillis - previousMillis));
  Serial.print(") >= ");
  Serial.println(interval);

  if ((unsigned long)(currentMillis - previousMillis) >= interval) {
      previousMillis = currentMillis;
  }
```

}

Now the following happens:

```
TIMING: 3076 - 2067 (1009) >= 1000
TIMING: 4080 - 3076 (1004) >= 1000
TIMING: 5084 - 4080 (1004) >= 1000
TIMING: 6087 - 5084 (1003) >= 1000
TIMING: 7091 - 6087 (1004) >= 1000
```

Why is the currentMillis getting so much higher every loop? It looks like it is sharing a pointer or something like that, because it adds the interval value everytime. I am confused!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the code you presented us is an incomplete picture of what you have uploaded on the **Arduino**, since on my device I obtain the following sequence

```
TIMING: 0 - 0 (0) >= 1000
TIMING: 0 - 0 (0) >= 1000
TIMING: 1 - 0 (1) >= 1000
TIMING: 32 - 0 (32) >= 1000
TIMING: 93 - 0 (93) >= 1000
TIMING: 153 - 0 (153) >= 1000
TIMING: 218 - 0 (218) >= 1000
TIMING: 283 - 0 (283) >= 1000
TIMING: 348 - 0 (348) >= 1000
TIMING: 412 - 0 (412) >= 1000
TIMING: 477 - 0 (477) >= 1000
TIMING: 541 - 0 (541) >= 1000
TIMING: 606 - 0 (606) >= 1000
TIMING: 670 - 0 (670) >= 1000
TIMING: 735 - 0 (735) >= 1000
TIMING: 799 - 0 (799) >= 1000
TIMING: 865 - 0 (865) >= 1000
TIMING: 929 - 0 (929) >= 1000
TIMING: 994 - 0 (994) >= 1000
TIMING: 1058 - 0 (1058) >= 1000
TIMING: 1127 - 1058 (69) >= 1000
TIMING: 1198 - 1058 (140) >= 1000
TIMING: 1271 - 1058 (213) >= 1000
TIMING: 1344 - 1058 (286) >= 1000
```

and it sounds correct given the code you provided.

---

Are you **sure** there isn't any **sleep()** call in your original source code?

*(perhaps you didn't upload the updated code on the device?)*

Comment: You are correct, there was a lot more code, and also an sleep in the code, i removed the sleep and now the problem is solved! I still do not understand the relation :)

Comment: @OlafvanderKaa If you sleep for *interval* milliseconds, then the loop is frozen for that amount of time, and the next time you hit *millis()* - which returns you the current clock time - you obtain a value that is higher than the *interval* threshold. What's unclear about this? Or I didn't understand your question?

Comment: ah yes, i confused myself when i was trying to get it to work and actually lowered my interval to less then the sleep, anyway problem solved, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @patrick-trentin's answer, it's looking very likely that your code is not the only thing you run on your Arduino. The code you see in your sketches is never the only code that the arduino runs. It handles for you the Serial data incoming, and if you use some other modules (like SPI or network) it's having some other code that runs in ISP, which are functions run regularly using a timer.

But the arduino CPU cannot run code in parallel. To mimic parallel behaviour, it's actually stopping your main loop, to run a subroutine (the ISP), which will read a byte coming in through Serial (for example), buffer it to then make it available to you using a nice method on the Serial object.

So the more things you do in those interrupt based subroutines, the less often you'll iterate your main loop, having it pass less often over the millis() comparaison you do.